# NHibernate SchemaExport.Execute does not create table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nunit, nhibernate-configuration

Learning NHibernate by following this tutorial [Your first NHibernate based application](http://nhibernate.info/doc/tutorials/first-nh-app/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.html) and I got to the point where you call
    `new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false);`
in a test method to export the schema (create the Product table) for verifying NHibernate was set up correctly

```
[Test]
public void Can_generate_schema()
{
    var cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.Configure();
    cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly);

    new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false);
}
```

The mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="MyFirstNHibernateProject" namespace="MyFirstNHibernateProject.Domain">
  <class name="Product">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"></property>
    <property name="Category"></property>
    <property name="Discontinued"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The configuration

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=MyFirstNHibernateProject.sdf</property>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The test passed and I can even see the output sql that create table but the table is not being created in the database (sql server compact), I refreshed the db in server explorer and it is still empty.

I have checked these posts
[NHibernate SchemaExport not creating table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346080/nhibernate-schemaexport-not-creating-table)
[NHibernate SchemaExport does not create tables when “script” is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817359/nhibernate-schemaexport-does-not-create-tables-when-script-is-false)
[NHibernate does not create Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311006/nhibernate-does-not-create-tables)
but none of them solve my problem. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use **full path** in the connection string:

```
// instead of this
<property name="connection.connection_string"
    >Data Source=MyFirstNHibernateProject.sdf</property>

// we should use 
<property name="connection.connection_string"
    >Data Source=C:\MyFirstNHibernateProject\MyFirstNHibernateProject.sdf</property>
```

Where the `"C:\MyFirstNHibernateProject\"` should be the full path to the `"MyFirstNHibernateProject.sdf"`

Also, in case you are suing CE 4.0 I would suggest to use this dialect:

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCe40Dialect</property>
```